# In Tomodachi Life, how can you make the apartments expand?

Tags: tomodachi-life

How do you make the Mii apartments expand in Tomodachi life?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Tomodachi Life Wiki](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Mii_Apartments)

> Mii Apartments has 3 upgrades not including the original building.
>   Each upgrade changes the number of available apartments and the
>   appearance of the building.
>
> The first upgrade will have a brownish, brick-like appearance. It will
>   expand to have 48 apartments.
>
> The second upgrade will have a grayish, stony-like material. It looks
>   very similar to how it looks in the beginning. It will expand to have
>   72 apartments.
>
> The final upgrade will have a elegant golden color. It will have a
>   gate with two trees in front of the office. It will expand to hold 100
>   Miis. The top four apartments will be in the center of the top floor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add enough Miis for it to expand. I'm not sure how many times it can expand, though.
EDIT: See the above answer.